# How to Validate illegal character username jQuery

Tags: jquery

this is the code

```
var account = $('#account'); 
account.on('keydown input',function(){

    // this check lenght of username only allow 4-15
    if((account.val().length > 3) && (account.val().length < 16)) {
            account.parent().removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        }
        else{
            account.parent().removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        } 
    });
```

how to improve it allow only a-z 0-9 -_[] no space

Comment: http://4rapiddev.com/javascript/jquery-allow-only-numeric-characters-or-only-alphabet-characters-in-textbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Use HTML5 Pattern attr to validate inputs

```
<input type="text" id="account" class="box" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\.-]*$"  />//it will allow only numbers and letters
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sVTCK/15/)